# When using clickhouse-jdbc, I occasionally encounter this error when querying data, and I wonder what the reason is?

Tags: clickhouse

```
ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseUnknownException: ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, port: 8123; xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8123 failed to respond
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.getException(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:91)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:55)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:24)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.getInputStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:633)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.executeQuery(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:117)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.executeQuery(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:100)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.executeQuery(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:95)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.executeQuery(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:90)
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8123 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.getInputStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:614)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a famous bug in JDBC-driver https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/issues/290